# how a Mac user creates unencrypted files on Windows shared folder?

Tags: mac, backup, encryption, ntfs

I have a Mac user who can read/write on a windows shared folder, but when he creates files on the shared folder, these files seem to be green (encrypted) and can't be backed up on our backup system. I searched for a solution instead of having to remove encryption each time before backing up but can't reach a suitable one. Is there a method which can easily solve this issue so a Mac user can easily write on a windows(NTFS) shared folder without files being encrypted?

Comment: Can you share further details on the state of these files? (e.g: screenshots)... Why can't you back them up? What error do you see? Is the issue actually that you can't open them in the relevant application because they're encrypted?

Comment: Yes exactly, because they are encrypted, they can't be written on NTFS backup drive. I need a solution so the files created by a mac user can be easily readable on windows so the backup system can work easily without any problems.

Comment: The error from backup system is Access denied to specific file/folder

Comment: Why would a backup system care whether a file is encrypted or not? It doesn't make sense that you should have to choose between security and backups. I doubt these files are encrypted. I bet you're just having a problem with access permissions, not encryption.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve the encryption issue?

Comment: We need some more details, because the file being "encrypted" seems misleading... Is it correct to assume you are running the "backup system" on some form Windows OS and are exporting a shared NTFS folder, which your Mac user is authenticated to via Active Directory? If not, what is the correct situation?